# Log Shipping Job Failed

Tags: sql-server-2016, transaction-log, log-shipping

I have a transaction log shipping configured. Job activity monitor shows that both Copy and Restore steps have failed, however, I see that backup files are in fact copied across to the secondary server and also the database has been restored successfully. What is going on?

Comment: what does the job monitor error log say? What are the reasons in Job Agent log?

Comment: Confirm the restore job detail does not state that logs were skipped. The SQL Agent Job will show succeed even when trn logs are not restored, but skipped due to log sequence number issues. It will not report failure if logs are skipped.

Comment: It would be more better if the issue has been mentioned in detail.